How to integration Spring-Authorization-Server to OAuth2 authorization_code with No /Login page?
In our case, we need a OAuth2 authorization_code flow with Spring-Authorization-Server to fetch per user tokens.
But, we dont need /login page cause we use api to fetch.
Such as, a user use customer front page, and its login with api.
How could i config my spring-authorization-server or where is a sample?
I except a authorization_code with api

In Spring Security Oauth2 client and Spring Authorization Server like this

front -> oauth2-client protected resource
oauth2-client no authentication redirect -> oauth2-client /oauth2/authorization/{id}
oauth2-client redirect -> authorization-server /oauth2/authorize
authorization-server no authentication redirect -> authorization-server /login page
authorization-server /login post authenticated -> oauth2-client login /login/oauth2/code/{id}
oauth2-client fetch access_token and refresh_token -> authorization-server
oauth2-client redirect -> pre-saved request

I dont want to this redirect, at least in front page there arent so many 302 request.
How could i config client and server?
I just want to this

front -> oauth2-client protected resource
oauth2-client no authentication forward -> oauth2-client /oauth2/authorization/{id}
oauth2-client forward -> authorization-server /oauth2/authorize
authorization-server no authentication redirect -> authorization-server /login page
authorization-server /login post authenticated forward -> oauth2-client login /login/oauth2/code/{id}
oauth2-client fetch access_token and refresh_token -> authorization-server
oauth2-client redirect -> the index page.


Could you explain this part? Such as, a user use customer front page, and its login with api. You mean there is a login page hosted somewhere else?

oauth2 is pretty much ALWAYS done without login, oauth2 is about authorization (that popup you would get when a third party app like facebook is asking for permissions to import your contacts from your gmail account). Just google spring oauth2 and look for some tutorial

@SuvinNimnakaSukka First, I have a custome front page to login user. In addition, I need this page login user with /login controller, /login controller will pull up a oauth2 authorization_code flow to authorize this user

@asgarov1 sorry, in my case it will be oidc, but use spring-authorization-server, its related oauth2

What you ask is going against the spec: in OAuth2 authorization code flow, collecting the user credentials is the responsibility of the authorization server.
The main motivations for that are:

improved security: hide user credentials from frontends and OAuth2 clients
implementing authentication complexity in a single place: user credentials can be more than just username & password in case of Multi-Factor Authentication, "magic-link", "remember-me cookies", etc.

Just learn how to style your authorization server UI to better integrate with the rest of your information system look & feel.

I agree with @ch4mp that this is against the spec.
However, if the OP still needs it, this is a workaround we use for integration tests. You might be able to tweak it to fit your requirements.

Perform the authorize call to the /oauth2/authorize endpoint. The response for this call will be 302 Found. Capture the response and extract the Location header and put this into a variable. The value of this header will be the URL of the login screen.
Perform a GET request to the URL you saved in the previous step and you will receive an HTML response. Parse the response and extract the value of the hidden input field named _csrf. Store this in another variable.
Perform a POST request to the same URL you saved in step 1 with your username, password and the _csrf token saved from the previous step. This request will also return a 302 Found response. Extract the value of the Location header once again and save it. This URL will be the authorization code request URL.
Perform another GET request to this autorization code request URL. You will again receive a 302 Found response code. Extract the Location header once again. This extracted URL will contain the authorization code. Extract the authorization code using a regex.
Perform the token call using the received authorization code.

You may follow this Postman script for more info. This method is a hack/workaround and not recommended at all.
AFAIU, exploring an option like Hypermedia Authentication API by Curity would be a good option for a use case like this.

The Spring-Authorization-Server has savedRequest for /oauth2/authorize in backend request redirect. And Its has more session using, If a device want to /oauth2/authorize, no cookie to use, How could i config it? Is there a sample?

I supplement my case

@bruce0828 From the edited content, step 7 of what you want to do doesn't make any sense. Ideally, the request should be redirected to the original destination after authn & authz. If you just want to get a token with username and password, consider using the password grant instead of the authorization _code grant.

in my case, it will be a oidc

OIDC is an authentication standard so you can use OIDC to perform authentication in both grants.
